# Bottom part of mousepad acting like physical click region

Tags: 22.04, mousepad

So my mousepad had some delay and after changing some stuff to fix it I finally got rid of it. However this introduced a new problem. The bottom part of my mousepad is acting like a physical right and left click. Meaning I cannot use the bottom part of my mousepad to scroll or move the mouse. I would like to use my full mousepad and remove the right side right clicking because I only use two finger right click.

Comment: Probably a hardware dependent issue.  What model/brand is your mousepad?  I just noticed that my MSI mousepad is similarly set up, and delays the mouse moved in that area, but they do show up if a move goes into the area or after a delay just moving in the area.

Comment: What did you change to fix the delay?

Comment: Sorry for the bad response but I honestly don't remember. I remember accessing some configurations via the terminal and changing some values.